# How to set margin to only one td tag inside a table in html?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to set `margin-right` property to only one `td` tag,but not able to achieve it.

```css
table {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table,
th,[![enter image description here][1]][1]
td {
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.fixed {
  padding: 10px;
}

.line:after {
  content: ' ';
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.border {
  word-spacing: 25px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  background: orange;
  border-radius: 5px;
  /*  border-style: solid;
 border-width: px; */
}

.fixed {
  padding: 10px;
}

.br {
  display: block;
}

.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.border1 {
  word-spacing: 25px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 5px;
  /*  border-style: solid;
 border-width: px; */
}

.border2 {
  word-spacing: 25px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  background: #bfbff2;
  border-radius: 5px;
  /*  border-style: solid;
 border-width: px; */
}

.border3 {
  word-spacing: 25px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  background: skyblue;
  border-radius: 5px;
  /*  border-style: solid;
 border-width: px; */
}

.border4 {
  word-spacing: 25px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  background: yellow;
  border-radius: 5px;
  /*  border-style: solid;
 border-width: px; */
}

.border5 {
  word-spacing: 25px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  background: #bfbfbf;
  border-radius: 5px;
  /*  border-style: solid;
 border-width: px; */
}

.boxed {
  padding-left: 2px;
  padding-right: 2px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border: 3px solid blue;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.border6 {
  word-spacing: 25px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  background: grey;
  border-radius: 5px;
  /*  border-style: solid;
 border-width: px; */
}

.right {
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<table border="0">
  <tr>
    <th class="text-center" colspan="4">Flight Puck</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th class="text-center">Behaviour</th>
    <th class="text-center">Description</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="fixed text-center"><span class="border bold">2210      924-16(267)     1030</span></td>
    <td class=" text-center"><span class="line text-center bold">Standard Flight Puck</span>
      <p>Departure time-Flight number-date-passenger Count(Including Non-Revs)-<span class="br">Arrival Time</span></p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="fixed text-center"><span class="border1 bold">2210      924-16(267)     1030</span></td>
    <td class=" text-center"><span class="line text-center bold">Standard Flight Puck</span>
      <p>Departure time-Flight number-date-passenger Count(Including Non-Revs)-<span class="br">Arrival Time</span></p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="fixed text-center"><span class="border2 bold">2210      924-16(267)     1030</span></td>
    <td class=" text-center"><span class="line text-center bold">Standard Flight Puck</span>
      <p>Departure time-Flight number-date-passenger Count(Including Non-Revs)-<span class="br">Arrival Time</span></p>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="fixed text-center"><span class="border3 bold">2210      924-16(267)     1030</span></td>
    <td class=" text-center"><span class="line text-center bold">Standard Flight Puck</span>
      <p>Departure time-Flight number-date-passenger Count(Including Non-Revs)-<span class="br">Arrival Time</span></p>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="fixed text-center"><span class="border4 bold">2210      924-16(267)     1030</span></td>
    <td class=" text-center"><span class="line text-center bold">Standard Flight Puck</span>
      <p>Departure time-Flight number-date-passenger Count(Including Non-Revs)-<span class="br">Arrival Time</span></p>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="fixed text-center"><span class="border5 bold">1215|<span class="boxed">|CX</span>499-02(267)1737</span>
    </td>
    <td class=" text-center"><span class="line text-center bold">Standard Flight Puck</span>
      <p>Departure time-Flight number-date-passenger Count(Including Non-Revs)-<span class="br">Arrival Time</span></p>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="fixed text-center"><span class="border6 bold">2210      924-16(267)     1030</span></td>
    <td class=" text-center"><span class="line text-center bold">Standard Flight Puck</span>
      <p>Departure time-Flight number-date-passenger Count(Including Non-Revs)-<span class="br">Arrival Time</span></p>
    </td>
  </tr>


  <tr>
    <td class="right fixed text-center"><span class="border6 bold">2210      924-16(267)     1030</span></td>
    <td class=" text-center"><span class="line text-center bold">Standard Flight Puck</span>
      <p>Departure time-Flight number-date-passenger Count(Including Non-Revs)-<span class="br">Arrival Time</span></p>
    </td>
  </tr>


</table>
```

[image: SAmple image]

Comment: `margin` does not work on `table`.

Comment: Do you need to use tables? You could use bootstrap grid to recreate the table structure and then format it with border,margins and any css you like. Or simply create your own structure

Comment: If i have to achieve a table like above what do i use then?

Comment: I have to use tables only here!

Comment: As i said, for me the easier way is to use the bootstrap grid sistem. it's responsive e full css editable.Or if your problem is simply to have some row with bigger cell just use colspan like in @VilleKoo answer. I'm worried about tables and i always try to avoid them.More about bootstrap grid at: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/

Answer (score 4):

Margin specification is ignored for table cells. 
Refer http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this.
is just a fast built of html+css to replicate bootstrap behavior and need more accurate fix of css, but it is something to start from.

My advice is still to use bootstrap or other similar frameworks

```css
.table{width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  display: table;
    position:relative;
 }
 .table .row{
  clear: both;
    position: relative;
  
 }
 .table .row + .row{
  border-top: 1px solid #333;
 }
 .table .col{
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
 }
 .table .col + .col{
  border-left: 1px solid #333;
 }
 .col.col25{
  width: calc( 25% - 1px ); /*-1 for the border between cell, in this example */
  background-color: yellow;
 }
 .col.col50{
  width: calc( 50% - 1px ); /*-1 for the border between cell, in this example */
  background-color: red;
 }
 .col.col75{
  width: calc( 75% - 1px ); /*-1 for the border between cell, in this example */
  background-color: yellow;
 }
```

```html
<div class="table">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col col25">col25</div>
  <div class="col col75">col75</div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col col25">col25</div>
  <div class="col col75">col75</div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col col25">col25</div>
  <div class="col col75">col75</div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col col50">col50</div>
  <div class="col col50">col50</div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col col50">col50</div>
  <div class="col col50">col50</div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col col50">col50</div>
  <div class="col col50">col50</div>
 </div>
</div>
```